# R-Programming for meta analysis in proportions

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

I need some guidance in R program. First I draw random samples from beta distribution by using rbeta, then I want to use these random samples as the probabilities and use them in Bernoulli distribution as the probability of success one by one to draw samples from Bernolli and then calculate pahat for all. e.g. first I draw random samples from rbeta(3,7,5) say. we get 3 samples, then use these 3 samples as the probability of success in bernolli to draw samples as rbinom(10,1,first probability), rbinom(10,1,2nd probability) and so on. Then calculate phat1, phat2 so on and lastly combine all phats to find pmeta. Can any one help me to write a program in R.Thanks

Comment: So its more about writing code than the mathematics? even if it is just the programme what is $p_{\text{meta}}$ in this context?

Comment: Combing all phats